# Prove/Disprove - Integral converges so the lim is 0

Tags: calculus

I received the following question and solution:
[image]

1) I didn't understand the professor's reasoning, why is the integral clearly equals to the sigma.

2) Why is it obvious that the $lim$ doesn't exist?

I would love it if someone could explain to me his explanation or give me another counter example that i could understand better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The professor's function is discontinuous. It is 0 except for an infinite collection of intervals where it is 1. The $n$th interval has length $\frac{1}{n^2}$, so integrating over that interval contributes $\frac{1}{n^2}$ to the integral. Hence integrating over the whole range gives the sum.

The limit obviously does not exist because we can find arbitrarily large $x$ with $f(x)=0$ and arbitrarily large $x$ with $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Oh, finally i got it! thank you very much for the explanation